# Error when navigating from sibling to sibling child route in feature module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Not sure why I get this error when trying to simply navigate from one child route to another.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'playlist-edit/display-tracks/artist/0i3rXQVnr4SE5pl3qtBM2o'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'playlist-edit/display-tracks/artist/0i3rXQVnr4SE5pl3qtBM2o'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
```

The strange thing is, it's showing the exact path to the route, as 'playlist-edit/display-tracks/artist/0i3rXQVnr4SE5pl3qtBM2o' - this is the route I want to navigate to.

I have tried many different ways, even moving routes about etc.

Feature module routes:

Initialisation route from parent module is:

/playlist-edit

```
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: PlaylistEditComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'playlist-add'
      },
      {
        path: 'playlist-add',
        component: PlaylistAddComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'display-tracks/type/id',
        resolve: {trackData: DisplayTracksResolverService},
        component: DisplayTracksComponent
      },
      {path: 'playlist/:id', component: PlayListComponent}
    ]
  }

];
```

I am in PlaylistAddComponent and want to navigate to 'display-tracks/type/id'

So I call this on router in that component:

```
this.router.navigate(['../display-tracks', entity.type, entity.id], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

Which to me says 'Go up one to parent route, then go down until you find /display-tracks/type/id

Seems straightforward.

I want to load DisplayTracksComponent.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Your route path is `display-tracks/type/id`. I guess you actually want it to be `display-tracks/:type/:id`

Comment: woops, don't know why those were removed. Params are params. Works now. Thanks @JBNizet